# How to populate HTML with ngFor without json array

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

How could i populate the HTML with simple JSON like:

```
{
    "id": 34,
    "name": "Tip 33",
    "description": "Tip description 33",
    "created_at": "2018-01-26 18:59:19",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-26 18:59:19"
}
```

I used the code as:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let data of searchResults">
    <ion-card-header>
      {{data.name}}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{data.description}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

But I get this error as :

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'Tip 33'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

My Code to fetch json is :

```
 this.apiService.getCareerDescription(data).retry(3)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.loading.dismiss();
        this.searchResults = data;
        //let obj = JSON.parse(this.searchResults);
        //console.log(obj);

        console.log(this.searchResults);
        ;
      }, (err) => {
        this.loading.dismiss();
      }
    );
```

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have an array you have a simple object. So `*ngFor` is not needed here. You can just access the properties via their name. The error says that your `searchResults` is an object, not array.

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      {{searchResults?.name}}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      {{searchResults?.description}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: i got this `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: Sorry, access via `searchResults`

Comment: You search result comes from an API? Yes?. So try to enforce you with `?` symbol. I have updated the post

Comment: `?` will enforce if the `object` is not `undefined` or `null` then access it's property

Answer (score 1):

For this we have to implement custom pipe.

Pipe:

```
@Pipe({id : 'key'})
export class custompipe implements PipeTransform {


transform(value, arts:string[]) : any {
let key = [];
for(let key in value){
key.push({key : key, value:value[key]});
}
return key;
}
}
```

And use it as:

```
<span *ngFor="#data of SearchResult I key">
Key: {{data.key}} , value: {{data.value}}
```